# Runtime of an algorithm: check if two strings overlap

Tags: algorithms

I need to know the average runtime of an algorithm that checks, if two arbitrary strings overlap. By overlap I mean that some suffix of the first string is equal to some prefix of the second string.

For example:
ABC and BCAB overlap
A and ABC overlap
ABC and AB do not overlap (but AB and ABC do overlap)

Assuming that the length of the first string is n, the length of the second is m. First, I have to read them, which takes O(n+m). Can you help me finding the next step and the runtime?

Thanks

Comment: You need to _decide on an algorithm_ before you can begin talking about its run time. So far you have just stated a problem, but not defined any algorithm for solving it.

Comment: And if you want the _average_ complexity of whichever algorithm you decide on (rather than the worst-case complexity), you also need to make some assumptions about the probability distribution of inputs.

Comment: That is why I am asking. My idea was to take the first char of the second string and compare it to the last char of the first string. If they are equal, they overlap. If not, I compare it to the second to last char. If they are equal, I check if the second char of the second string is equal to the last char of the first string and if they are equal, they overlap. And so on... I wonder if there is a nicer way?

Comment: A method of *practical* speed-up (but unfortunately not of theoretical value, this is still $O(\min(n,m)^2$): It may be possible to iteratively compute "hashes" of suffixes/prefixes and make an explcit characterwise comparison only when hashes match